# Unable to calculate integral for cross-section volume

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, cross-sections

I am trying to determine the volume of a solid by cross-sections, and I am having trouble determining the integral I should use to calculate it.

[Graph in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXxZO.png)

The base is bounded from $x = -8.216$ to $x = -4.537$.

The top graph is $\frac{1}{100}x^2+0.5$, and the bottom graph is $\frac{1}{20}x^2-2.2$.

I am attempting to find the volume when the cross sections are equilateral triangles. How would I create an integral to solve this?

Comment: I am assuming that your first value for $x$ is a decimal approximation to the exact value: $-3\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}$. Would you prefer exact answers? If so what is the second $x$ as an exact value? Also can you provide details of the orientation of the equilateral triangles. Is the vertical distance the base or the height of the triangles?

Comment: Decimal approximations of the exact answer is fine for my purposes.

The vertical distance represents the base of the triangle. The height should be adjusting to the distance of the base (i.e. the base gets larger, the height gets taller).

Here is another image that may help clarify: http://i.imgur.com/WioUus4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your reference to triangular cross-section means orientated like this:

[image]

If you consider one of the triangles the area of it is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}b^2$ where $b$ is the base. In this situations the base is the difference between the two curves: $\frac{1}{100}x^2+\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{20}x^2-\frac{11}{5}\right)=\frac{27}{10}-\frac{1}{25}x^2$.

To find the volume you need to integrate all the areas:

$$\int^{-4.537}_{-8.216}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{27}{10}-\frac{1}{25}x^2\right)^2\ dx$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\int^{-4.537}_{-8.216}\frac{729}{100}-\frac{27}{125}x^2+\frac{1}{625}x^4\ dx$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{729}{100}x-\frac{9}{125}x^3+\frac{1}{3125}x^5\right)_{-8.216}^{-4.537}$$

$$=4.97745\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the help I needed.